# Popular Python open source CMS like Drupal

Tags: python, content-management-system

I wonder if there is an open source CMS coded in Python that is as big as Drupal (or Joomla or Wordpress).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Plone](http://plone.org/) is an open source python powered CMS.

Answer (score 12):

You are looking for [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/).  (Edited to say: OK, it's a web application framework, but there's lots of overlap. [Django-CMS](http://www.django-cms.org/) is maybe more what you want, but is in no way as big as Drupal or Joomla.)

Answer (score 1):

check out [Web2py](http://www.web2py.com/) it comes tons usefully stuff

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for similar alternatives and have found http://www.lfcproject.com/blog/release-10-final. At least they just had a release. Looks promising.
Btw, development of Django-CMS looks either dead or stale :\

Answer (score 1):

[Tendenci](http://tendenci.org) was recently released into the open source community and is written in Python on a Django framework.

Tendenci CMS comes with a ton of features that require plugins/modules typically with other CMS' like membership management, selective permissions, event registration and event calendar,  jobs board, video and photo galleries, etc.

You can download Tendenci on Github at https://github.com/tendenci/tendenci.